# Getting Values from Multiple Comboxes in same sub

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have an excel sheet workbook with 2 sheets. One sheet has data imported from an external source and the other sheet then filters this data. I want to be able to select a date range to narrow done the filtered results.

To do this, I have 4 comboboxes, one checkbox, and one button. When the button is clicked I want my sub to first see if the checkbox has been checked. If it has not, then just run filter the data regardless of date. If the checkbox is checked, I then want to look at the four comboboxes. The first two will have the start year and start month and the last two will have the end year and end month. I want to take these values and filter my data using this criteria as well when the checkbox has been checked.

The issue I am having is that I cannot get the value of the combobox. For example, I named one of my comboboxes "Start_Month". In my sub, when I select the sheet with the combobox first, then I use "Start_Month.Value" to check the combobox value, but this gives me runtime error 424 "Object Required".

Does anybody know how to get the value of four different comboboxes in the same sub or is this not possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your code, thanks.

Comment: Is it an ActiveX control or a form control? With the ActiveX variety you  should definitely be able to do what you are trying to do, the way you seem to be doing it.

Comment: I believe I used form control, I will try ActiveX though and see how that works